# Windows 8 - Can not create a very basic network between 2 PCs

Tags: networking, windows-8

i have been trying to set up a simple network between my windows 8 desktop and windows 8 laptop, since last week. I am still surprised that i have to come to a form to ask this, but believe me i have tried every thing in my knowledge and capacity.

**Laptop - Windows 8**

Connected to Linksys Cisco Router, using wireless connection

All firewalls off on laptop (i.e. domain, private, public)

**Desktop - Windows 8**

Connected to Linksys Cisco Router, using LAN cable

All firewalls off on desktop(i.e. domain, private, public)

**Linksys Cicso Router**

Firewall off

Shared a folder in C and D drive of Laptop and Desktop (Allowed everyone full access)

both desktop and laptop have following settings in **Network and Sharing Center > Advanced Sharing Setings**

---

### Private:

**Network Discovery:**

Turn on network discovery (with turn on automatic setup of network connected devices)

**File and printer sharing:**

Turn on file and printer sharing

**HomeGroup connections:**

Use user accounts and password to connect to other computers
(have also tried Allow windows to manage homegroup connections)

---

### Guest or Public:

**Network Discovery:**

Turn on network discovery

**File and printer sharing:**

Turn on file and printer sharing

---

### All Networks:

**Public folder sharing**

Turn on sharing so any one with network access can read and write files in the Public folders

**File sharing connections**

Use 128 bit encryption to help protect file sharing connections

**Password protected sharing**

Turn off password protected sharing

---

with all of the above settings, i still can not do this on my laptop:

\\DESKTOP

and can not do this from desktop

\\LAPTOP

also tried their respective local ip addresses, but still get this error "Windows can not access \\LAPTOP" or "Windows can not access \\DESKTOP"

both computers show each other in the "Network" window, but when i click on icons, i still get the above error.

I can not ping each other

I have also tried creating the homeGroup network, but can not see a homegroup created by another pc to join in ...

Comment: I can not ping each other -> Well, this is certainly a hint that things aren't right. Can both computers ping the router? Are both devices configured to actually BE in the same network? What does ipconfig /all say about your network configuration on your computers?

Comment: yes both can ping router ... both can access the router on 192.168.1.1 ... and therefore both have same Default Gateway and DNS Server

Comment: What are the IP adresses and Subnet Masks of your DESKTOP & LAPTOP?

Comment: 192.168.1.120 for Desktop
192.168.1.137 for Laptop

255.255.255.0 subnet masks

Comment: Is the router isolating your two connections? Some routers have "AP isolation" that prevents clients from talking to each other.

Comment: i do not know what AP Isolation is, will have to check. But i think that may not be the case, as the the same router was working for the same two machines when they had Windows 7 installed about 2-3 weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

sorted ... but i do not know how ...

I stopped my wifi ... and connected my laptop with a LAN cable ... both PCs were then able to access each others shared folders .... i then connected my laptop again via wifi ... and both were still able to access each other's shared resources ...

the only thing that changed in after putting laptop back to its wifi ... is the ip address of the laptop ... its now 192.168.1.134 ... earlier it was 192.168.1.120 ...

Thanks everyone ... can i mark this an answer ???